# Modify original input array within a loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, reference

How can I add a new key/value pair to an existing array inside of nested foreach loops and have that pair persist outside the scope of the loops?

```
foreach ($rss->items as $item)
{
    $item['feed_id'] = $feed_id;
    echo $item['feed_id'] . "<br/>"; // works as expected
}
    
foreach ($rss->items as $item)
{
    echo $item['feed_id'] . "<br/>"; // nuthin..... 
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you want is this (for the first loop):

```
foreach ($rss->items as &$item) {
```

The `&` will make `$item` be a reference, and any changes you make to it will be reflected in `$rss->items`

Comment: Thanks I don't know how many times I have come up against this problem. Can read from the $item but not write to it. That is because it makes a copy I guess.

Answer (score 0):

PHP offers several ways to mutate iterable data.

- Use `array_map()` with the union operator to append a new elements to each row. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/lvF4Y)

  ```
  $feedId = 42;
  $rss->items = array_map(
      fn($item) => $item + ['feed_id' => $feedId],
      $rss->items
  );
  var_export($rss);
  ```
- Telling a `foreach()` loop to modify the original array instead of a copy of the input array is done by prepending an ampersand to the row variable declaration. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/p482g)

  ```
  $feedId = 42;
  foreach ($rss->items as &$item) {
      $item['feed_id'] = $feedId;
  }
  var_export($rss);
  ```
- Iterate a copy of the input array, but then access the keys and use them to affect the original array. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/uXfnL))

  ```
  $feedId = 42;
  foreach ($rss->items as $key => $item) {
      $rss->items[$key]['feed_id'] = $feedId;
  }
  var_export($rss);
  ```

---

As a divergence of the proposed scenario, but topically related, if the input is an array of objects, a `foreach()` will iterate the original array (not a copy) without needing a prepended ampersand. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/F6ABM)

```
$items = [
    (object) ['foo' => 'bar1'],
    (object) ['foo' => 'bar2'],
    (object) ['foo' => 'bar3'],
];

$feedId = 42;
foreach ($items as $obj) {
    $obj->feed_id = $feedId;
}
var_export($items);
```